# What is an example of a perfectly played checkers game?

Tags: checkers

The board game American Checkers on an 8x8 board was weakly solved in 2007 and shown to be a draw ([PDF link](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring13/CSCI-UA.0472-001/Checkers/checkers.solved.science.pdf)).  What is an example of a perfectly played game of checkers?

Comment: "Checkers was solved.." [citation needed]

Comment: @Nij We're not Wikipedia. Checkers being solved is "common knowledge" among anyone who follows this sort of thing and the reference is in the intro section of the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Draughts isn't solved, it's weakly solved, which is a major difference to anybody with a mathematics background.

Comment: Per Wikipedia a game is weakly solved if there is a known complete game where each played move is optimal.  This is what the question is asking for for Checkers.  Note the draw does no have to be prolonged as long as possible if that is not available.  What is more likely is that there is a known game where the side moving first can force a draw and it is known there is no winning strategy.  Is this game available now for the public, some 10 years after the game is solved?  And if so, where can it be viewed?  This is what the question is asking.  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Note that there may be more than one "optimal" move from a given configuration. In particular, [this page](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~chinook/news/) lists several 3-move openings that were *each* proven to lead to a draw.

Answer (score 8):

Checkers was weakly solved in 2007: it was proven that the [Chinook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinook_(draughts_player)) algorithm could never lose a game. So to get a perfectly played game you could have Chinook play against itself, but I can't find the final version of Chinook online or a record of its later games. You can check out its earlier games against humans [here](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~chinook/matches/index.html) - most of those are draws, though there's no guarantee they're "perfect" since it's a human and an earlier version of Chinook playing.

Answer (score -2):

**Chinook can definitely still lose a game.** When the proof was announced in 2007, it was unbeatable in 28 of the 156 3-move ballots and, theoretically, beatable in the other 128. It still is. In fact, in a match of indefinite length against a genuine oracle it would definitely lose. Currently the KingsRow program (Ed Gilbert) is stronger than Chinook - it's phenomenal - though still far from perfect.

In a 40-game match between Chinook and the best 'version' of the late Dr Marion Tinsley, it would be a very close call - Marion could still win, although Chinook would be the favourite by a very tiny margin. Richard Pask Author of Complete Checkers and Checkers for the Novice